# Unknown column in subquery - mysql

Tags: mysql

I am very close to completing this difficult query.  It's quite long, so hopefully not too overwhelming.  But in my case statment in the select block I am referencing a union from my where statement.  It is giving me "MySQL Database Error: Unknown column 'U.EmpID' in 'where clause'".  Any help would be much appreciated.  And here is the query:

```
SELECT U.EmpID,
   CASE
      WHEN     ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM (SELECT *
                           FROM timeclock_copy tp
                          WHERE     PunchEvent = 'breakin'
                                AND DATE(tp.PunchDateTime) =
                                      '2013-11-12'
                                AND tp.EmpID = U.EmpID) AS s) > 1)
           AND ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM (SELECT *
                           FROM timeclock_copy tp
                          WHERE     PunchEvent = 'breakout'
                                AND DATE(tp.PunchDateTime) =
                                      '2013-11-12'
                                AND tp.EmpID = U.EmpID) AS s) > 1)
      THEN
         "MULTIPLE BREAKS"
      ELSE
         "ONE BREAK"
   END
      AS Lunch
FROM ((SELECT `enter`.EmpID,
                `enter`.PunchDateTime AS `time`,
                DATE_FORMAT(`enter`.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y')
                   AS 'Punch Date',
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                              `enter`.PunchDateTime,
                              '2003-05-01 00:00:00')
                   AS `delta`
           FROM timeclock_copy AS `enter`
          WHERE `enter`.`In-Out` = 1)
        UNION
        (SELECT `leave`.EmpID,
                `leave`.PunchDateTime AS `time`,
                DATE_FORMAT(`leave`.PunchDateTime, '%m-%d-%Y')
                   AS 'Punch Date',
                -TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                               `leave`.PunchDateTime,
                               '2003-05-01 00:00:00')
                   AS `delta`
           FROM timeclock_copy AS `leave`
          WHERE `leave`.`In-Out` = 0)) AS U
       LEFT JOIN testclb.prempl pe ON u.EmpID = pe.prempl
 WHERE DATE(U.`time`) >= '2013-11-12' AND DATE(U.`time`) < '2013-11-13'
GROUP BY date(U.`time`), EmpID
ORDER BY U.EmpID, U.`time` ASC
```

Comment: on the 4th to last line, would that lower case 'u' be your issue? Just a guess hence the comment, not answer :)

Comment: good catch, no that didn't fix it though

Comment: Stupid question but column EmpID really exist?

Comment: Yes it does, I just checked :)

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in FROM clauses cannot be correlated with the outer statement. I think this is why you are getting the Unknown column 'U.EmpID' in 'where clause'" error.